# Detecting moving objects in Images with trifocal tensor and trilinear constraints

Tags: computer-vision, computational-geometry, object-detection, multiple-views, projective-geometry

I want to use trifocal tensor to detect moving objects. but I have a problem.

I already know what is the 3 camera projection matrixes(P matrixes) in 3 image frames.

I assume that 3 P matrixes are [I|0], [I|-1; 0; 0], [I|-2; 0; 0].

A 3D point X is projected on 3 image frames. This 3D point moves(the last number is homogeneous value) : (0, 0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1, 1), (2, 0, 1, 1)

So it is projected on x(0, 0, 1), x'(0, 0, 1), x''(0, 0, 1).

I calculated trifocal tensors(T1, T2, T3) and trilinear constraint output with x, x', x''. T1, T2, T3 are [-1, 0, 0; 0, 0, 0; 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0; -2, 0, 0; 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1; 0, 0, 0; -2, 0, 0].

A point X moves but the output of trilinear constraint is 0(3x3 matrix) and it isn't detected as moving object.

What did I do wrong? please help... I need your help.... T.T